# mysql service restarted during user being connected lead to failing service

Tags: systemd, mysql, services

I have performed a charset change via my.ini into utf8 and forgot a user loggen in in another terminal session, when I performed a service restart.

Initially systemd reported a problem stopping the service while the service was still working. After a system reboot through systemd was never able to start the service again.

```
$ sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code)
  Process: 2750 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2747 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2750 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 2751 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─2751 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─2838 sleep 1
systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

That is the current status of the service as reported by systemd.

Also when I try starting the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

I get a **failure** analyzed to the following from `journalctl`:

```
$ journalctl -xe

-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
 pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log/mysql ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mysql.service
 pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by user(uid=0)
 mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
 (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
 pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
 Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
...
```

Which suggests having something to do with the `pam` authentication module.
But I don't know how to deal with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by logging in as root using:
`sudo mysql -uroot -p`
pasword:******
and then exiting
mysql> exit
and the service started working (and restarting normally).
As it seems the service was in a **zombie state**!
Even though reported as **not running** by `systemd` it was actually running because I was able to login with root and issue a `show databases;` command which worked like a charm!
Strange issue indeed! By the way if someone knows why I need to use `sudo` to login as `root` in the database while all other users are logged in with a simple call to `mysql` client and their credentials. I would love to understand why! There seems to be strange relationship between linux users and `mysql` users which I have never really understood.